# POS Histogram with Stanford POS Tagger

Tags: pos-tagger, part-of-speech

I need to tag the words in Tweets, using Stanford POS Tagger.

As explained here [1](http://www.galalaly.me/index.php/2011/05/tagging-text-with-stanford-pos-tagger-in-java-applications/), I used the Class ***MaxentTagger*** and then the method:`maxtagger.tagString("This is a sample text");`

This produce the output:

> This_DT is_VBZ a_DT sample_NN text_NN

Now I have to create, for each tweet, an histogram of the occurrence for each tag in the tweet. I have searched in the JavaDoc, but found nothing useful.

If I have to create the histogram myself, how can I read the output in other ways than a string (for example, the list of the tags)?

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest to use the method tagCoreLabels() or tagSentence() instead. E.g. with tagSentence() you get back a list of TaggedWord from where you can easily access the pos tag using the tag() method. That should account words or models with POS tags that contain "_".

To create a List from a simple sentence string, use the PTBTokenizer, e.g.

```
List<CoreLabel> tokens = new PTBTokenizer<CoreLabel>(
  new StringReader(s),new CoreLabelTokenFactory(),"invertible").tokenize();
```

Use the PTBEscapingProcessor to escape characters that have a special meaning in the parser models:

```
new PTBEscapingProcessor().apply(tokens)
```

I believe there is no specific support for histograms in the Stanford tools, but I may be wrong.

Comment: Seems good, but how can I get an object like:
java.util.List<? extends HasWord>
from a String text?